# Помогите пожалуйста сделать простой шаблонизатор, на основе ob_start

Tags: php

Есть такая заготовка

```
$header = template('header', ['title' => 'Hello World!']);
$content = template('content', ['content' => "Lorem ipsum...", 'meta' => 'Author info']);
$footer = template('footer', ['copy' => "Copyright ". date('Y')]);

// ...skipped logic

echo $header, $content, $footer;

/**
 * @param  string $template
 * @param  array  $vars
 * @return string
 */
function template($template, $vars) {
    // place your code here
    // ...
}
```

Нужно что бы работало так

```
!-- header.phtml -->
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title><?=$title?></title>
</head>
<body>
<!-- content.phtml -->
<div class="container">
    <p><?=$content?></p>
    <p><?=$meta?></p>
</div>
<!-- footer.phtml -->
<footer>
    <?=$copy?>
</footer>
</body>
</html>
```

Вообще не понимаю, как это сделать или покидайте ссылки, что бы я изучил нужные статьи.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вы точно считаете что уже готовы написать собственный шаблонизатор? Дело хорошее конечно, если осилите будет круто, но сейчас есть много нормальных, доступных шаблонизаторов.

По вашему вопросу, итак, допустим есть файл `header` с содержимым:

```
!-- header.phtml -->
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title><?=$title?></title>
</head>
<body>
```

Это наш шаблон, в нем мы хотим чтобы вместо `<?=$title?>` в дальнейшем встраивались наши писюльки, можно делать по разному:

**Парсер:**

Парсер - самый распространенный тип шаблонизаторов, основная идея его в том: не допускать `PHP` код в файле с шаблоном, а уходить в некоторые абстракции, например переменные обозначаются как `{% title %}`, можно и `<?=$title?>` (этот вариант и будем ниже рассматривать).

```
function template($template, $vars) {
    $TPL = file_get_contents('путь к директории файла/'.$template.'.phtml');
    return str_replace(array_map(function ($v) { return "<?=$$v?>";}, array_keys($vars)), array_values($vars), $TPL);
}

$header = template('header', ['title' => 'Hello World!']);
```

Смысл в том, что мы не выполняем `PHP` код, а просто заменяем. Дело не заканчивается простыми переменными, и парсить начинают целые конструкции, например `foreach` в шаблонизаторе `Laravel` выглядит так: `@foreach ($users as $user)`, в `smarty` так: `{foreach from=$myArray item=foo}`. Т.е. уходят в абстракцию.

Конкретно по нашему примеру, минуса такого простенького подхода очевидны, если `title` будет не задан, то вместо пустоты (что было-бы логично), останется висеть наш тег, надо усложнять и уходить в это болото шаблонизатора, а там уже потребуется препроцессор, а это ууууу.....

Как другой вариант, действительно можно **инклудить**:

Я на практике малова-то такого встречал, но делается как-то так:

```
function template($template, $vars) {
    foreach ($vars as $key => $value) {
        ${$key} = $value;
    }
    ob_start();
    include('путь к директории файла/'.$template.'.php');
    $TPL = ob_get_contents();
    ob_end_clean();

    return $TPL;
}

$header = template('header', ['title' => 'Hello World!']);
```

Такой вариант прикольный, но не безопасный, и возможно мало-читаемый, но есть смысл ему существовать, почему-бы и нет.

Comment: Спасибо, буду пробовать